# Public/Private key authentication for Ruby Net::SFTP

Tags: ruby, net-sftp

I am having trouble finding documentation for specifying a key for SFTP authentication.

Would like to have something like:

```
export SOME_PRIVATE_KEY="$(cat tmp/some-certs/privatekey.pem)"

# then somewhere in the code
private_key = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(ENV['SOME_PRIVATE_KEY'])

Net::SFTP.start(ftp_host, user, key: private_key) do |sftp|
  sftp.dir.entries('/path/to/folder').each do |remote_file|
     # ...
  end
end
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`Net::SFTP.start` passes its `options` hash directly to `Net::SSH.start`, so we should [look to its documentation](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/net-ssh/net-ssh/Net%2FSSH.start). It lists three options that look relevant:

> - `:keys` => an array of file names of private keys to use for publickey and hostbased authentication
> - `:key_data` => an array of strings, with each element of the array being a raw private key in PEM format.
> - `:keys_only` => set to `true` to use only private keys from `keys` and `key_data` parameters, even if ssh-agent offers more identities. This option is intended for situations where ssh-agent offers many different identites.

The answer to a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6905934/using-ruby-and-net-ssh-how-do-i-authenticate-using-the-key-data-parameter-with) suggests that you may need to use all three:

```
Net::SFTP.start(ftp_host, user,
  key_data: [],
  keys: "tmp/some-certs/privatekey.pem",
  keys_only: true)
```

If you want to use the raw key data from the `SOME_PRIVATE_KEY` environment variable instead, it ought to look like this:

```
Net::SFTP.start(ftp_host, user,
  key_data: [ ENV["SOME_PRIVATE_KEY"] ],
  keys: [],
  keys_only: true)
```