# Net::SFTP with .ppk key authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, sftp, net-sftp

I've been train to setup the connection from Ruby on rails to a SFTP server, but it fails on everything I try!

This is what I am using, following the documentation and some articles on stackoverflow.

Net::SFTP.start( host, user, key_data: [], keys: "key_location", keys_only: true)

I currently removed the passphrase from the .ppk key.

No matter what I try I get the prompt for password! 
user@host's password:

I've tested connecting to the sftp server with WinSCP and works fine using a passphrase or not.

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44400201/4160532) ?

Comment: Figured it out .. used the openssh key!

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out .. used the openssh key!